# LocalHost is not loading after making changes to node.js i am running the commands on linux subsystem in windows

Tags: node.js, linux

I am trying to run below node.js program in port 4242

```
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.end('Hello World\n');
});

server.listen(4242, () => {
  console.log('Server is running...');
});
```

Initially it runs in the browser(*localhost:4242*) but when i make any changes(Ex: Add or remove a console.log)  to the file and re-run the node server with the command

```
node demo.js
```

local host takes forever to load with no result.

I am using ***NPM version 6.14.8*** and ***Node version v15*** installed on Linux subsystem(***Ubuntu 20.04 LTS***)  in Windows 10 to run the node js server.

Below are the resolution steps I tried.

1. Re-installed Node version v15 and also tried with lower version v12.
2. Disabled and Enabled Linux subsystem and re-installed Ubuntu( Ubuntu 20.04 LTS)
3. Added 127.0.0.1 to HostFiles.
4. Cleared Cache,Prefetch and Temp and tried from different browsers

But None of these worked.

Please let me know if any changes needs to be done,I would be really grateful .

Answer (score 0):

Finally,I was able to figure out the mistake I was making. I was trying to stop server with the command Ctrl + Z which didn't kill the node process and led the port to be still in use and didn't allow the browser to access the port when i re-run the node server. Now that I terminate the server with Ctrl + C the node process is getting killed and once I make changes , save the changes and re run the node server , the changes are getting reflected in the browser .